# Unity AudioClip references are missing

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I'm encountering a very annoying issue :) From time to time, on apply prefabs or saving the project, audio clips references are vanished.

To be more specific, I have an array of AudioClip, usually it contains 1 or 2 audios. The names of the audio files can be as follows: `Something-Something-VER 2@2017-08-29.cpr`
So it contains: white-space, hyphen, at sign

So, from time to time, the references is gone and instead it has "None (Audio Clip)", and inside the prefab I can see that it was changed to: -{fileID: 0}

Anyone else encounter this issue?
I'm suspecting that it happens because of one of the special characters, but before I'm changing my whole project sounds files, I wanted it to be sure.

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your inspector panel change your view as debug mode (upper right side). Then check your settings in there.